# ComboBox is Databound and I want to show the data on the textbox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

A little tip or help would be very much appreciated, please and thank you.

I have a `DataBound ComboBox` from my `MySql` table named `"formmaintenance"` which has 3 columns namely `FormCode`, `FormName`, `FormDescription`,  `Combobox DisplayMember` is `FormCode` and `ValueMember` is `FormCode` as well, I have 2 `TextBoxes`  named as `txtName` and `txtDesc`.

What I would like to happen is when I select an item in Combobox (ex: form101) I want to display the value of `FormName` of selected item (ex name: Paper) on `txtName` and `FormDescription` on `txtdesc`.

I have yet to know how to start with this, since I'm really new with Vb.Net.

Here is my Code(**Updated**)

```
 If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.ConnectionString = "Server = localhost; Username= root; Password =; Database =forms"
            Try
                conn.Open()
                MsgBox("Connection Established")
                Dim dt As New DataTable

                Dim sql = "SELECT FormName FROM formma WHERE  FormCode = '" & cmbCode.Text & "';"
                Dim Result As String


                cmd.Connection = conn
                cmd.CommandText = sql
                Result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                da.SelectCommand = cmd

                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                If Result IsNot Nothing Then
                    txtName.Text = Result.ToString()

                End If

            Catch ex As MySqlException
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())

            End Try
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: @Thinhbk well so far I've just been trying different queries and haven't gotten to the solution or anything at all... I'm also wondering if I could do it in another matter aside from databound items, but I still needed to load the formcode column into my combobox...

Comment: Show us the snippet you have tried, we will happily extend it for you. To write everything from scratch for you is a turn off really

Comment: @nawfal Ohh Ok sorry bout that. Sure I'll add my codes here, I keep forgetting. Let me try and fix it up a little bit more.

Comment: @AlexLuthor please post it in your question so that its clear. You can edit your question

Comment: @nawfal Have placed my codes on my question. to make it simplier what I wish is to fill 2 textboxes(txtName, txtDesc) which depends on the Combobox Choice (cmbCode) Thanks

Comment: You say combobox is databound to table `formmaintenance` but in your query you are selecting from `incomingdeliveries` table?

Comment: ohh right sorry, A little confusion let me change that.

Comment: @nawfal I managed to do it.... Im so sorry for taking up your time after playing with it a little and read that Executescalar is better for textboxes. I managed to output the formname into txtname, I wish to paste my codes here, athough I dont know how to paste codes here in the comments. Although I managed to do it for 1 txtbox only, what do I do to show 2 diffrent datas from 2 diffrent columns into 2 textboxes?

Comment: That's fine. Though additionally there are many things you need to change in your code. Like one, you should move your db code to a separate class. The UI class should have only UI stuffs to do, in other words it should have minimal code. Two, you should not directly use string in your sql, that will cause sql injections. Please use parameterized queries. Try reading about it, its very important!. Thirdly, Your way of fetching Name each time is not the ideal way to go about this. You should be able to get the required string from the object itself that's residing in the combobox

Comment: wow, thanks, hmm, okay I guess I still have much to learn... although I'm still not pretty sure on the 3rd one.. how would I get the formname from the db (which is the 2nd column or index[1]) through the combobox? would you be kind enough to give a little demonstration please? just a little hint, I won't ask for the whole code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, here's the tip.

1- Load data from DB and bind it to the combobox:

```
     Dim tableFormula as new DataTable("formula");
     using (Dim sqlConn as new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; Username= root; Password =; Database =forms"))
     {
        Dim sqlQuery  as string = "SELECT FormCode, FormName, FormDescription FROM formma;"
        Dim cmd as new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);
        Dim da  as new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
        //create dataTable and bind it with dataSet:
        da.Fill(tableFormula);
     }              
     //setting dataSource to comboBox:
     this.cmbCode.DataSource = new BindingSource(tableFormula, null);
```

2- On SelectedIndex_Changed event handler of cmbCode combobox, set text based on selected item of the combobox.

```
        if(cmbCode.SelectedItem != null) 
        {
            txtName.Text = ((DataRow)cmbCode.SelectedItem)["FormName"].ToString();
            txtdesc.Text = ((DataRow)cmbCode.SelectedItem)["FormDescription"].ToString();
        }
```

HTH.

Comment: thanks I've already managed to get my desired output... I appreciate your help... also I believe what you've done is for CS I think... but really, thank you...

Comment: Yes, sorry for some mistake I made due to converting C# --> VB.NET.

Comment: it's okay, I bet some people would really be able to use your code.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

In SelectedIndex_Changed Event of combobox, you should write following

```
Dim st As String = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=forms;UID=root;"
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(st)
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FormName, FormDescription FROM formmaintenance WHERE  FormCode = '" + cmbCode.Text + "'"
conn.Open()
Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If dr.Read() Then
    txtName.Text = dr(0).ToString()
    txtdesc.Text = dr(1).ToString()
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciated. I have tried it and it works, but  I would also wish to see what nawfal is telling me to do.. I believe I would need to really learn it in the near future...